skewed top and bottom border, and space between border

As defined on title, I was trying to create a bordered container. The top and bottom border seems skewed to an angle, but in my code, I didn't define the skewing. Also, there are spaces between border.
leftContainer := container.NewBorder(
    canvas.NewLine(color.White),
    canvas.NewLine(color.White),
    canvas.NewLine(color.White),
    canvas.NewLine(color.White),
    nil,
)
ctx:= container.New(layout.NewHBoxLayout(),leftContainer)


The previous answer is excellent, but I wanted to highlight that border container (like all) is just a layout system and the left / right items are positioned with no graphical elements.
Where lines were added in your example is where content belongs. Anything other than line would look perfectly straight straight, but a line, when instructed to fill a space (the default) goes diagonally from top left to bottom right.
Lines are not normally placed where content would go and are more commonly used in custom widgets or containers where the coder is positioning them manually for specific outcomes.
